# In a multi-sig transaction, if one party refuses to sign, what happens to coins?

Tags: multi-signature

In a multi-sig transaction, if one party refuses to sign, what happens to coins?  Are the coins forever lost, or is the transaction voided as if it never was attempted?

Comment: A transaction that is not properly signed is not a valid transaction and thus no different from random junk data. Literally nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only valid transactions transfer control of balances. Since the transaction was never completed, the balances remain under control of the original owners.

Answer (score 2):

The transaction is not fully signed, so it will not be included in a block, and thus the coins will not be moved from where they are. Only what's in a block can move coins, and anything that causes a transaction to not verify will cause that transaction to not be included.

Answer (score 1):

voided as if it never was attempted

assuming here you're spending from a multisig wallet and hence >1 parties need to sign. As @user36303 and @Murch♦ pointed out, if the TX is not fully signed, its not really a TX yet and the original balance on this multisig wallet is still the unspent balance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like those two scenarios are the same thing.

If a transaction output requires two signatures to be spent, but one is never available, then the coins on that output aren't going to go anywhere.  This is just like where a transaction output only requires a single signature, but it isn't available.

However, this all depends on what type of multisig.  For example, if it's a 2-of-3 and one party refuses to sign, then the other two can spend the coins.  If it's a 2-of-2, then the coins are stuck.

Comment: Do the "stuck" coins in the unsigned transaction count as spent (and therefore lost) or do they count as unspent?

Comment: They are unspent.  In this scenario, there is no way to prove that they can never be spent.

Comment: If they were provably unspendable, would it make a difference?

Comment: They would still be unspent, but the rest of the world would know those coins are dead.

Comment: Wouldn't they know the coins were dead when they were spent elsewhere after the multi sig transaction failed?